# Short code to solve this java string and number situation

Tags: java, string

i came across this problem whereas user need to enter a certain series of number in one input, then the program will output back the number one by one. For example, the user entered 4 6 8, then the program will output 4 6 8 to the user.

The code that i have done is like this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N;
        String num;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter number:");
            num = in.nextLine();

            ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int x = 0; x < num.length(); x++)
            {
               char c = num.charAt(x);

               if(Character.getNumericValue(c) >= 0 ){
                   numbers.add(Character.getNumericValue(c));
               }

            }

            for(int n=0; n<numbers.size(); n++){

                 System.out.println(numbers.get(n));
            }

    }
}
```

But i think it is not really efficient as it is quite long for just doing a simple task. So, could you suggest anything that is much simpler? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. Is it OK for user to input lets say `10 a bc 123` if yes then how program should react? Could you add some correct and incorrect examples of user input?

Comment: You want to output the digits of the input, each on a different line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the numbers are in one line then this can solve the problem:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] tokens = reader.readLine().split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
```

See [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for more info.

Comment: Why use `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner`?

Comment: I know that efficiency is not the issue in this question but I prefer `BufferedReader` because is more efficient than `Scanner`. Although in this specific situation(read a line) I think both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` performs equal.

Comment: hey thanks for the solution! i need the tokens so that i can use each of the number to do more complex calculation with them :)

Answer (score 1):

Set delimitter on Scanner and read each number a int

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\\s");

System.out.println("Enter number:");
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    numbers.add(in.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea:

```
String num = "4 6 8";  // user's input
System.out.println(num.replaceAll("\\s+", "\n"));
```

```
4
6
8
```

If you want to ignore everything except the numbers you can use `"[^\\d]+"` instead of `"\\s+"`.

Comment: That is perfect...If the tokens not necessarily need to be numbers.

Comment: @RafaelRendonPablo If he wants only the numbers he can use `"[^\\d]+"` instead of `"\\s+"`.

Comment: This line "If he wants only the numbers he can use "[^\\d]+" instead of "\\s+"" was added after my comment. :)

Comment: @RafaelRendonPablo Indeed, thanks for bringing it to my attention.